# setsockopt(...) cannot recognize IP_TTL for IPPROTO_IP on Ubuntu

Tags: c, sockets

I have written a traceroute program written on OS X.
I am trying to port it to GNU/Linux.

```
[@osx]
>> sudo bin/traceroute www.google.com

Warning: www.google.com has multiple addresses; using 173.194.69.99
...
```

To make it compile on GNU/Linux, I added `_GNU_SOURCE` feature test macro.

```
[@ubuntu]
>> sudo bin/traceroute www.google.com

error setting socket options: Invalid argument
```

The issue is at:

```
 85     send_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
 86     if(send_socket == -1){
 87        fprintf(stderr, "\ncannot create send socket");
 88        freeaddrinfo(dest_addrinfo_collection);
 89        return EXIT_FAILURE;
 90      }
 91     error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(int));
 92     if(error != 0){
 93        perror("\nerror setting socket options");
 94        freeaddrinfo(dest_addrinfo_collection);
 95        return EXIT_FAILURE;
 96      }
```

Looks like `setsockopt(...)` cannot recognize `IP_TTL` as socket option.
However I see `IP_TTL` as a socket option for `IPPROTO_IP` level.

I am using `SOCK_DGRAM` as my sending socket to avoid preparing my own `ICMP` packet.

Comment: Have you bound the socket already at the point where you call `setsockopt`? I'm not sure if this is supposed to be required, but it might be on Linux...

Comment: And by the way, omitting lines 86-90 was probably a bad idea since that may be where the issue lies...

Comment: @R.. updated the question with 85-95

Comment: Ok, try binding (to `INADDR_ANY`, port 0; this will get the kernel to assign you a port) before you call `setsockopt`.

Comment: what's the type and value of `ttl`?

Comment: yep! the issue was that I specifying incorrect sizeof `ttl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, my `ttl`variable was an unsigned short.

```
-    error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(int));
+    error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(unsigned short));
```

---

### UPDATE

In addition I had to `option_len` was different for different platforms.

```
-    error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(unsigned short));
+#if defined(__APPLE__)
+    error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(&ttl));
+#elif defined(__linux)
+    error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
+#endif
```

---

### UPDATE

```
-  unsigned short          ttl = 1;
+  socklen_t               ttl = 1;

-#if defined(__APPLE__)
-    error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(&ttl));
-#elif defined(__linux)
     error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
-#endif
```

Comment: why did you make `ttl` an `unsigned short` when the man page tells you to use `int`? Also, giving `setsockopt()` the size of a pointer to what you're passing instead of the size of what you're passing seems wrong.

Comment: Actually it's wrong again. Type socklen_t is used for storing socket-relevant sizes, which has no connection to TTL at all. The only thing that specified about TTL is that it should be able to store values from 1 to 255, though its type is not mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

That's why you should use sizeof(variable) in lieu of sizeof(type), since if the type changes, you're screwed once again. This is strongly adviced and recommended not only in this case, but also when you use malloc(), etc.

```
error = setsockopt(send_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
```

Comment: somehow setsockopt wants sizeof(ttl) on Linux and sizeof(&ttl) on Mac OS X which looks very weird.

Comment: Nope. It always wants sizeof(ttl). It may be the case that on mac sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(intptr_t) == sizeof(ttl) == sizeof(&ttl) (i. e. the pointer is of the same byte length as a long integer). sizeof(&ttl) is explicitly known, it's sizeof (void *). It wants sizeof(ttl) as it has to figure out how much bytes in memory does the passed in pointer point to.

Comment: if I use sizeof(ttl) on Mac OS X, it returns me errno 22, which means invalid argument

Comment: Maybe your linux system is a 32-bit OS while OSX is 64-bits (or the other way around is also possible). If that is the case, then sizeof(int) may give something else than what you were expecting.

Comment: well both my Linux and OS X are 64-bit